# How Show result Query in textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have data tabel vendor:

| ID | vendor Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | bbb |

with query

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `vendor`)
```

how show results all data in textarea html like this

```
<Textarea>
1-AAA
2-bbb
</textarea>
```

Comment: How about reading one of the many [PHP Mysql tutorials](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql/)? Then learn a bit more about HTML, et voila, you've done it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```php
<?php

// ... database connection here

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vendor");

?>
<textarea>
    <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['ID'], '-', $row['vendor_Name'], ' ';
        }
    ?>
</textarea>
```

Also consider using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of `mysql_*` functions, because they are deprecated and removed in PHP > 5.5.

Same solution with PDO:

```php
<?php

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=...;dbname=...", "username", "password");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM vendor");

?>
<textarea>
    <?php
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $row['ID'], '-', $row['vendor_Name'], ' ';
        }
    ?>
</textarea>
```